# How to show author's avatar in the post meta data with plugin `user-avatar`

Tags: plugins, author

I'm using `user-avatar`, and I want to show user icon in the post meta data.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/

I'm writing like this.

`<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
<?php echo get_avatar(); ?>`

It shows only default "nobody" avatar.

If I write like `<?php echo get_avatar("myemail@example.com"); ?>`, then it shows my avatar through `user-avatar` plugin.

So if I can get the author's emails, it works all fine.

I tried to get the email by `<?php the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>`. But it doesn't return the email, but it outputs directly.

I'm stuck now. How can I set user avatar in post meta area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_the_author_meta()`, this function returns data, it doesn't display it.
For example:--

```
<?php $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email'); ?>
```

For more information check it in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)